# Calling post method on link click jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I wan to use `anchor tag` to post page on another page in `MVC`.
Problem is this when I click on a hyperlink it takes to that controller. But it does not hit the post method.
It hit the get method.
Can I create a method on `acnhor` in jquery which post the page to another page.

suppose I have an anchor on page1

```
 <a href="/home/action">click Here</a>
 <input type="hidden" value="2"/>
```

and it should hit the post method on home action.

Comment: Links will always do `GET` actions. To do a `POST`, you need to use a form. Good UI also would say that `POST` requests should always be buttons as well.

Comment: @lonesomeday thanks but is there any way in jQuery by which we can call form post method and tell the browser to post on that action.

Comment: Well, you *can* do it with Javascript. But it is a phenomenally silly idea. Why not just put `/home/action?inputname=2` (whatever the `name` of the `input` element is) into the URL of the link?

Answer (score 1):

You have to define the form with your hidden field

```
 <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="click_me">click Here</a>
<form method="post" action="/home/action" id="form_submit">
 <input type="hidden" value="2"/>
</form>

$(document).ready(function(){
$("#click_me").on("click",function(){
$("#form_submit").submit();
})
})
```

Make sure  you have included `jquery`

Comment: and how I will get on the other controller.

Answer (score 1):

use  tag.

```
<form method='post' name='frmPost' id='frmPost' action='/home/action'>
<a id='clickme'>click Here</a>
 <input type="hidden" name='hiddenValue' value="2"/>
</form>

$('#clickme').click(function(){
$('#frmPost').submit();
});
```

Hey, this may help you

Comment: and how I will get on the other controller.

Comment: @Shekhar, how sure about your question, are you asking how to get the hidden value? if so at actionAction $_POST['hiddenValue'] will get you the value